# .htaccess Redirect from subdomain to domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've tried a bunch of examples here on SO and modifed them, but none are exactly what I need and as a result either fail with 500 server errors (meaning the rewrite rules are wrong) or redirect just the subdomain to the domain and not any of the full URLs of pages.

I need to redirect all URLs under blog.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/blog,
i.e. redirect blog.mydomain.com/page1  to   www.mydomain.com/blog/page1

This

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://mydomain.com/blog/
```

redirects all URLs of blog.mydomain.com  to the root of mydomain.com/blog/, not the full URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch permanent (.*) http://mydomain.com/blog/$1
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I was missing the URL matching bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to redirect one domain to another, but should work fine for subdomains/subdirectories:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That 404's with a url like blog.mydomain.com/myurl

Comment: How is your subdomain set up? Are you using cPanel?